# C program using while- weird counter error if counter>8

Tags: c, while-loop, counter

This program finds out the max and min of 10 numbers using the while loop.

If i set the number of inputs from the users to 8 or less it works, if i set it to >8 (say 10) it produces an error (program stops responding) when the user tries to enter the 9th number.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    int x, max, min;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Introduceti un intreg\n");  // Enter a number
    scanf("%d", &x);
    max = 0;
    min = x;  // Set min to number
    do
    {
        i++;
        if (i > 10) break;
        printf("Introduceti un intreg\n");  // Enter a number
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x > max)
            max = x;
        if (x < min)
            min = x;
    }
    while (max > min);

    printf("max este %d\n", max);
    printf("min este %d\n", min);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's readable.

Comment: And check the return values from `scanf`

Comment: [Works for me...](http://i.imgur.com/VPLHVax.png) Did you maybe forget to recompile?

Comment: [Works for me too!](http://ideone.com/YWdIEQ) - As @AmadeusDrZaius said, clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Don't know how to check the return values from scanf.

Comment: I did use clean and recompile. Still not working, i'm using dev c++ and it's very buggy. Sadly they require i use it. Anyone know any other fast to setup ide? Just so i can test things outside of dev c++.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius and hagubear it worked for the given input of your choice. Check my answer.

Comment: Your loop condition is flawed... what happens if your first two numbers are the same?  For that matter, is your loop condition ever supposed to be false?

Comment: Know what is supposed to be true of your variables at the inside top and bottom of your `do`. Then check that that is so.

Comment: The simplest way to check values is to a print statement.

Comment: @Stack_token, G.Samaras and Dmitri are both right - your loop condition of `while ( max > min )` is what is terminating the output prematurely. Why do you need that condition anyway?

Comment: It's not the code(mine worked for a friend, also tried a few from here), it's a cmd.exe erorr . 0x0000142 Error the application was unable to start correctly.

Comment: 1. Do not keep editing your question if it changes it to a new question; ask a new question. 2. Always give minimal sufficient input and output including errors & give the details of the system you are using. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Stack_token Regarding the IDE question, if you're going to use Dev-C++, please use the [Orwell Dev-C++ IDE fork](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.com/) instead of the outdated and probably broken Bloodshed Dev-C++ IDE. You might also consider the [Code::Blocks IDE](http://www.codeblocks.org/) (you'll want to download a "binary" in case you don't know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see why using a do-while loop when you know how many iterations you want to perform. You should use a for loop instead (do-while works too, but for loop is intended to be used in situations like these).

Moreover, you had an `else` when checking for `min`, which was not needed, since you want to check if every number given from the user is `min` or `max`.

Notice that the for loop starts from 1, since we read one number outside the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  int i, x, max, min;
  printf("Introduceti un intreg\n");  // Enter a number
  scanf("%d", &x);
  max = x;
  min = x;  // Set min to number
  for(i = 1; i < 9; ++i) {
    printf("Introduceti un intreg\n");  // Enter a number
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if(x > max) {
      max = x;
    }
    if(x < min) { // here you had an else, but it was wrong
      min = x;
    }
  }

  printf("max este %d\n", max);
  printf("min este %d\n", min);
  return 0;
}
```

---

About the return value of `scanf()` mentioned in one comment, you can always check the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

---

If you need to that with a while loop, then you should do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  int i = 0, x, max, min;
  printf("Introduceti un intreg\n");  // Enter a number
  scanf("%d", &x);
  max = x;
  min = x;  // Set min to number
  while(i < 9) {
    printf("Introduceti un intreg\n");  // Enter a number
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if(x > max) {
      max = x;
    }
    if(x < min) { // here you had an else, but it was wrong
      min = x;
    }
    i++;
  }

  printf("max este %d\n", max);
  printf("min este %d\n", min);
  return 0;
}
```

Here the counter `i` is increased at the end of every loop and the condition to stop is `i < 9`, since we have already read a number outside the loop.

Comment: The problem said to only use while.

Comment: Initially used while, but i tried a lot of things to make it work.

Comment: "Use 'while' " means use use `while () ...`, use 'do-while' means `do {...} while (...)`.

Comment: Still the error. It's not the code, it's a cmd.exe erorr .  0x0000142 Error the application was unable to start correctly.

Comment: @philipxy I asked because in the code in the question there is a do-while. Stack_token, then the problem is for sure not the code! So I suggest you accept one of the answers so that the question appears as answered, since the code if fixed and then try to search help about dev-c++.

Comment: @Stack_token & G. Samaras I meant an earlier comment for Stack_token: Do-while is not while. If the problem says use while then use while.

Comment: @Stack_token & G. Samaras There should only be one point where x is prompted for and input.

Comment: @Stack_token & G. Samaras Error: Initially max should be set to x not 0. Error: In the second version i should be intialized to 0 (otherwise it is undefined per C language definition).

Comment: I agree @philipxy, good catch! :) I gave you a +1 to another answer you made (and I liked it) as a reward.

Comment: Feel free to peruse my oeuvre!

Answer (score 0):

Do not write else if for min, because you need to check both max and min at the same time.Also for 10 numbers it should be i>=10.And you can make while to 1, because it will break at i=10 anyhow.Here is your working code.Also initially max should be set to x.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    int x, max, min;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Introduceti un intreg\n");  // Enter a number
    scanf("%d", &x);
    max = x;
    min = x;  // Set min to number
    do
    {
        i++;
        if (i >= 10) break;
        printf("Introduceti un intreg\n");  // Enter a number
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x > max)
            max = x;
         if (x < min)
            min = x;
    } while (1);
    printf("max este %d\n", max);
    printf("min este %d\n", min);
}
```

Comment: Still error, i'm pretty sure it's not the code, it's something else. Users said that the first version worked fine too. Tried clean and rebuild. Devc++ is very buggy for me.